# Javascript Generate Multidimensional array of 2 sizes

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I cannot figure out the best way to dynamically generate a multidimensional array with 2 different sizes.

We have a UI that requires a row of 4 items, then 3. This pattern would repeat until the content in the array has been spent.

This is essentially what I need to do:

```
// Convert
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

// to
const rows [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]];
```

This is what I currently have, it is only converting the arrays to 4 each.

```
 const buildRows = (arr, length) => arr.reduce((rows, val, i) => (
  i % length == 0 ? rows.push([val]) : rows[rows.length-1].push(val)
) && rows, []);
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you care if the input `array` get mutated?

Comment: I prefer not to mutate the data, but at this point I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following solution will mutate (empty) the input array `array`:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

let result = [], i = 0;
while(array.length) {                          // while there still items in array (array is continually getting shrunk untill it is emptied (array.length === 0))
  result.push(array.splice(0, i++ % 2? 3: 4)); // cut the first 3 or 4 numbers depending on the index of the cut i (if i is pair, then cut 4, else, cut 3) and then push the cut-out items into the result array
}

console.log(result);
```

If you don't want to mutate it, then use `slice` instead of `splice`, but you'll have to provide the start index of the cut:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

let result = [], i = 0, next = 0;                      // next will be the index from which the cut will start
while(next < array.length) {                           // there is still items to cut
  let itemsToCut = i % 2? 3: 4;                        // determine how many items we are going to cut
  result.push(array.slice(next, next + itemsToCut));   // cut the items between next and next + itemsToCut
  next += itemsToCut;                                  // increment next by the number of cut-out items so it will point to the next item
  i++;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

I suggest a more self-documenting generator solution where even & odd row-sizes are not hardcoded but supplied via arguments:

```js
function* reshape(array, ...rows) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) for (let row of rows) {
    if (i >= array.length) return;
    yield array.slice(i, i += row);
  }
}

// Example:
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
for (let row of reshape(array, 4, 3)) console.log(row);
```

A true generator purist would simplify `reshape` by first introducing a `repeat` generator:

```js
function* repeat(iterable) {
  while (true) yield* iterable;
}

function* reshape(array, ...rows) {
  let i = 0;
  for (let row of repeat(rows)) {
    if (i >= array.length) break;
    yield array.slice(i, i += row);
  }
}

// Example: 
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
for (let row of reshape(array, 4, 3)) console.log(row);
```

Comment: I know this is JavaScript, but it just doesn't look so :D

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using `Array#reduce`, a pointer to the last place, and a `step` variable that alternates between 3 and 4:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

let last = 0;
let step = 0;

const result = array.reduce((r, num, i) => {
  if(i === last + step) { // when the previous sub array is full
    r.push([]); // add another sub array
    
    last = i; // mark the start index of the current sub array
    
    step = step === 4 ? 3 : 4; // alternate the step
  }
  
  r[r.length - 1].push(num); // push the number to the last sub array
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Straighfoward and easy-to-read solution:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

const r = [];
let chunk = [];
let l = 4;

array.forEach((el, i) => {
  if (chunk.length < l) chunk.push(el);
  if (chunk.length === l) {
    r.push(chunk); chunk = [];
    l = ( l === 4 ) ? 3 : 4;
  }
})

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution. Clearly everyone is having a good time with this one.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

function divide(array, idx, num, result)
{
  if(array.length <= idx) return result;
  result.push(array.slice(idx,idx+num));
  return divide(array, idx+num, num === 4 ? 3 : 4, result);
}


console.log(divide(array, 0, 4, []));
```

Answer (score 2):

We can think of it as slicing elements from the array in a loop. It's just that we need to alternate between 4 and 3 instead of a constant value to slice.
We can parameterize alternating values by passing them in a function instead of hardcoding it in the solution like below:

1. Use `Array##slice` and
2. Just swap current and next like this by using `destructuring assignment` to achieve the solution.
3. Sub array sizes(4,3) can be modified outside actual logic or can be passed in a function to have flexible solution.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

function TransformArray(array, current, next) {
  let start = 0,
    ans = [];

  while (start < array.length - 1) {
    ans.push(array.slice(start, start + current));
    start += current;
    [current, next] = [next, current]; //swap the count of array size
  }
  return ans;
}

console.log(TransformArray(array, 4, 3));
console.log(TransformArray(array, 3, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's kind of a different way of doing this, I'm expanding a bit to allow you to arbitrarily pass array lengths, this allows the PM to change their mind any time and it isn't a big deal.

This could be cleaned up a bit, I wanted to leave it more verbose to make it easier to read.

```
// Setup the function getting in:
//     an array
//     first array's length
//     second array's length
const arrayParser = (inArr,arr1len,arr2len) => {
    // Create a new array.
    let outArr = [];
    // Basic forEach is basic, we need the value and the index.
    inArr.forEach((val,idx) => {
        // If the index's modulus of the total of the two array lengths is:
        //   0 OR the first array's length
        // Push a new empty array.
        if (idx%(arr1len+arr2len)===0 || idx%(arr1len+arr2len)===arr1len) {
            // Create a new array with the current value
            outArr.push([]);
        }
        // Push the value to the last array in the out multidimensional array
        outArr[outArr.length-1].push(val);
    });
    // You got it.. return the array.
    return outArr;
};

// Single Dimensional Array
const singleArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];
// Parse it.
// Expects:
//        A Single Dimensional Array
//        Length of the first array
//        Length of the second array
console.log(arrayParser(singleArray,10,4));
console.log(arrayParser(singleArray,2,4));
console.log(arrayParser(singleArray,3,4));
console.log(arrayParser(singleArray,4,3));
console.log(arrayParser(singleArray,1,2));
```

This works, because you know the length of each of the inner arrays, so you don't really need to figure out anything.

Here's a 4,3 set broken out.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

Push a new array at 0 and 4.

           4+3
index     total   Modulus
 0     %    7    =   0 <-- push [], push 1
 1     %    7    =   1 <-- push 2
 2     %    7    =   2 <-- push 3
 3     %    7    =   3 <-- push 4
 4     %    7    =   4 <-- push [], push 5
 5     %    7    =   5 <-- push 6
 6     %    7    =   6 <-- push 7
 7     %    7    =   0 <-- push [], push 8
 8     %    7    =   1 <-- push 9
 9     %    7    =   2 <-- push 10
10     %    7    =   3 <-- push 11
11     %    7    =   4 <-- push [], push 12
12     %    7    =   5 <-- push 13
13     %    7    =   6 <-- push 14

Returns

[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10,11],[12,13,14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty and as much as I try to write functional code, it's pretty easy with a while loop...

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
const newArray = [];

let i = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
  let four = array.slice(i, i + 4)
  if (!(four.length > 0)) {
    break;
  }
  newArray.push(four)
  i += 4;
  let three = array.slice(i, i + 3);
  if (!(three.length > 0)){
    break;
  }
  newArray.push(three);
  i += 3;
}

return newArray
```